# how to use null parameter in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, null, find

I inputed a parameter, and using mongodb.

My query is

```
db.collections.find({"tags":parameter});
```

I want to run query, when parameter is "" (null or "").

It will be

```
db.collections.find({"tags":""});
```

It is returned empty value.

How can I use input parameter null or "" in mongoDB?

**EDIT**

I'm sorry. I'm beginner in here, so sorry.

I want to get all the values returned when I type null

For example, it looks like this my collections,

```
collections
{    
  "_id": 0,
  "tags": ["happy", "sad", "nice", "bad"]
},
{
  "_id": 1,
  "tags": ["bad", "gloomy"] 
}
```

I want the same result as below.

```
> Db.collections.find ({"tags": ""})
{
  "_id": 0,
  "tags": ["happy", "sad", "nice", "bad"]
},
{
  "_id": 1,
  "tags": ["bad", "gloomy"]
}
// Return all collections.



> Db.collections.find ({"tags": "happy"})
{
  "_id": 0,
  "tags": ["happy", "sad", "nice", "bad"]
}
// Return matching collections.
```

but, db.collections.find ({"tags": ""}) brings out the results of that result is empty.

How can I print out all the results when I enter a null value?

Comment: use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

Comment: db.collections.find({"tags":{$in:[""]}}) is same result. I want to return all value, when I input null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `null` value can be represented in several ways, depending on the language that wrote to the database in the first place, you need to use a combinations of things. Your query will need to look something like

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{"tags":{"$type":"null"}}, {"tags": {"$exists":false}}, {"tags":""}]})
```

Since BSON has a concept of Null, we have type check to see if the field exists but simply has no value. In addition to this, the field could not exist at all, so this must be explicitly checked for. Finally, depending on the language and the way the field was serialized, an empty string is a possibility.

Note that

```
{"tags":null}
```

and

```
{"tags":{"$type":"null"}}
```

are essentially the same thing.

Here is a quick example

```
> db.test.insert({"abc":null})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56670b3072f096ee05a72063"), "abc" : null }
> db.test.find({"abc":{$type:10}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56670b3072f096ee05a72063"), "abc" : null }
> db.test.find({"abc":{$type:"null"}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56670b3072f096ee05a72063"), "abc" : null }
> db.test.find({"abc":null})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56670b3072f096ee05a72063"), "abc" : null }
db.test.find({$or:[{"tags":{"$type":"null"}}, {"tags": {"$exists":false}}, {"tags":""}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56670b3072f096ee05a72063"), "abc" : null }
```

As you can see they all work, although the last query is the most thorough way of testing.

**EDIT OP CHANGED QUESTION**

You cannot find all values when you type `null`. That is a value and potential state for a field. You need to do an implicit `$and` here to get what you want.

```
db.collection.find({tags:{$exists:true}, tags:{$in:["happy","sad"]}})
```

How do you actually assemble this in code? Well, that depends on your language, but here is some pseudo code.

```
def getTags(myTags):
    if (tags is None):
        db.collection.find({ tags: { "$exists": true } })
    else:
        db.collection.find({ tags: { "$exists": true }, tags: {"$in": myTags } })
```

You can also get crafty by using an explicit `$and`

```
def getTags(myTags):
    query = [{ tags: { "$exists": true } }]
    if (tags is Not None):
        query.add({tags: {"$in": myTags } })
    db.collection.find({ "$and": query })
```

I hope this answers your question more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Pete.However, it's not the answer I want. I updated the question.

Comment: This is not at all what you asked. I will update my answer when I have a few minutes.

Comment: @Garafano Thank you, I am trying  the first method.

But, if statements was messy when I stroked two or more variables.
So I  tried to find another way . But unfortunately I found nothing.

Comment: @whdals0, I realize it isn't what you are expecting, however all database query languages I am familiar with will yield the same results. You are basically asking for a query language to translate `find everything where x is null` to mean `find everything`. You need to add a conditional in *your* code to determine what to pass to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer isn't suitable for the question(at least nowadays).

In [MongoDB >= 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/).

you can use the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) operator as follow :

> assuming that your parameter name is `tagsParam` and its value may be an `Array` or `null`

```
db.collections.find({ 
    $or: [ 
       { $expr: !tagsParam || !tagsParam.length }, 
       { tags: { $in: paramter } }
    ] 
});
```

In this case you will get the desired result if the parameter value was `["happy"]`, `null`  or even an empty array `[]`.